# JS Is there a way to check if an event exists?

Tags: javascript, events, animation, webkit

I am trying to detect if a certain webkit event '`webkitAnimationEnd`' is supported by the browser, to do so I like to check if the event exists. But I can't seem to figure out how. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Is your question about this event in particular, or in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/) suggests that this ought to work:

```
'onWebkitAnimationEnd' in document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: +1 Looks good, though _technically_ the presence of an event-handler-as-property is not the same as knowing that the browser will fire the event. (The browser could expose the property but have a broken implementation, or you could easily have the event implementation without the event-handler-as-property.)

Comment: Well I am going to assume that if the event exists through this approach the browser will support it and fire it when appropriate.

Comment: Hm, this does not evaluate to `true` in Chrome 18 or Safari 5. Might be a problem, time to dig deeper.

Comment: I am checking on the object anyways and it works in Safari at least.

Comment: @Mark interesting. What version of Safari? Does the element have CSS3 animation rules set?

Comment: Hmm weird now it doesn't work, I thought it did. I am sorry I am going to investigate this further as well.

Answer (score -3):

What do you mean by "is supported"? Assuming you mean *"Will be fired by the browser under a particular set of circumstances"*, then you need to simply recreate those circumstances (via script) and see if an event was fired; you can use a timeout handler to respond in the negative if the event was never handled.

Detect features by testing them, not by looking anywhere else.

Comment: I suspect he wants a run-time check so he can execute a different code path for clients that don't support the event.

Comment: @Matt I suspect so too, but that is not contrary to my answer. You can easily, procedurally create the elements/styles/whatever necessary, register the event handler, and a 'timeout' handler, and determine if your event handler was ever called.

Comment: ahh, I gotcha.  I thought you were suggesting test in each browser a-prioi